# Issue with hibernate-validator - 5.2.4.Final

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator

I was using hibernate-validator - 4.2.0.Final lib for GroupSequenceProvider and it was working fine.

I have upgraded my application to hibernate-validator - 5.2.4.Final and I am getting null pointer exception.

I am following below link:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.4#chapter-groups

Below is my code:

```
     public class MyGroupSequenceProvider implements DefaultGroupSequenceProvider<CustomObject> 
   {
     @Override
     public List<Class<?>> getValidationGroups(CustomObject customObject) 
     {
       List<Class<?>> defaultGroupSequence = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
       defaultGroupSequence.add(CustomObject.class);
       if (customObject.getType().equals("Number") { 
           defaultGroupSequence.add(NumberChecks.class);
       }
       else if (customObject.getType().equals("String")) {
         defaultGroupSequence.add(StringChecks.class);
       }
       return defaultGroupSequence;
     }
  }
```

Also,

below is my model class:

```
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @Getter
  @GroupSequenceProvider(MyGroupSequenceProvider.class)
  public class CustomObject {

  @NotNull
  private String type;

  @Length(min = 2, max = 4,groups = NumberChecks.class)
  @Length(min = 2, max = 7, groups = StringChecks.class)
  private String value;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get an NPE? Can you share a stacktrace?

Comment: When I debug , I am getting customObject as null in getValidationGroups method

Comment: That's odd. Any chance you can provide an isolated reproducer and attach it to a new issue in our tracker?